# Trying to make my own vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have been working on this vb script for around an hour trying to get it to work there is many skype spammer scipts but i want to make one that includes a random number generator my script is this i call it at the moment "Skype_randizer_mk1"

If anyone would be able to take a look at it it would be greatly appreciated.
When i was posting this the website said i had to indent this so it may look a little strange

The Delay variable is the amount of time it will take to enter another number
I don't mind if this program makes only numerical values that is what i intend for it to do

```
set shell = createobject ("wscript.shell")
dim max
dim min
dim delay
max = 100
min = 1
delay = 0.00000001
for i = 1 to 5
    randomize
    intnumber = int((max - min + 1) * rnd + min )
    wscript.echo intnumber
    Next
for b=1 to delay 
    shell.sendkeys (intnumber)
    wscript.sleep(delay)
if not isnumeric(delay) then
wscript.quit
end if
msgbox "You have 5 seconds to get to your inputbox."    
wscript.sleep ( 5000 )
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it is currently formulated, your question is not very clear. Please include in your question (by clicking Edit under the question) details like: What is the code expected to do? What is it the error you are getting? You can maybe take some time to read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck!

Comment: Download [Windows Script Documentation](http://windows-script-documentation.software.informer.com/download/). There are some _basic_ examples in the `script56.chm` there.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of problems with your code:-

1. You should ALWAYS declare your variables using `Dim`: e.g. `Dim shell`
2. You are missing a `Next` for one of your `For` loops
3. Line 10 doesn't make much sense. It says: `for b=1 to delay`, but delay = 0.00000001, so your loop will never run. Also, why does this section even need to loop?  I think you probably just want an `If`/`Then`/`Else`
4. Line 11 should probably say `shell.SendKeys`, not `strshell.sendkeys` as this is an uninitialised variable
5. Line 13 is checking for a numeric `delay` value. How will this ever be anything other than numeric when you are assigning a value of `0.00000001` on line 4 and it never changes.  As a result, you will not exit the script until the `for` loop on line 5 has executed 5 times.

Comment: Line 10 is the part where it keep generating random numbers because i intend to use this as a skype spammer so the number keeps changing also i changed the second loop to a "b" because the first one was an "i" do you have to do that? and there was a strshell.sendkeys because someone else made a skype spammer but it says text and only what you enter and not constantly changing strings how would i use If / Then / Else to do the same thing? I will post another comment here to show what i have changed and to see if it will work